# Test Node.js/Socket.io connection in browser

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am new to Node.js and Socket.io. I am supposed to connect through a server using Android but I want to test first if I can connect to Node/Socket server using a browser like for example typing http:server:8000/?v=1&username=test&password=test. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think the tutorial, on socket.io webpage (http://socket.io/), is a good start for you.

In a nutshell, you create a server that will listen for events like this piece of code:

```
// Load socket.io module and start listening on port 8000
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // This is trigerred on a login event sent from the client
  socket.on('login', function(data) {
    // Do what you want with your data here
    // Then emit a response
    socket.emit('login-response', {data: 'ok'});
  });
});
```

And on the client side you create this:

```
<!-- Load the socket.io library -->
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  // Connect to your server
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  // Emit your login event
  socket.emit('login', {username: 'test', password: 'test'});
  // When you retrieve the login response
  socket.on('login-response', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I have already tried something like that. I followed a tutorial in Youtube. I am working on a project that already has a server set up. I couldnt understand much of the codes yet but if for example in one of its apps (js) it is connecting to a server.com:8000?username=xxx&pass=xxx how come that even connecting to server.com:8000 gives me a handshake error?